# Start and Stop build automically in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My project need to start build at morning 9.00 a.m and it should stop at 5.00 p.m automatically. Is there any plugins are available in jenkins. pls help me on this.

I am using Jenkins Pipeline to build my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Jenkins job, there is a section `Build Triggers` and within that an option `Build periodically`.
This is what you need.

From there it is just a [simple cron notation](https://www.lenar.io/jenkins-schedule-build-periodically/), for example:
`H 9-17 * * 1-5`
This will build every hour, 9-5 Monday to Friday.

You can also schedule different times on the weekend, one example:

```
H 9-17 * * 1-5
H 9-10 * * 6-7
```

This would add 9-10am on the weekend.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are trying to say. What do you mean by 'project wants to run'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: From Monday to Friday my build should start running at morning 9 a.m to evening 5.00 p.m that we will achieve through build trigger. At the same time I don't want to run my build whole day on Saturday and Sunday it is enough to run for 5 to 10min. For that do we have any configuration?

Comment: @VaradharajanThiruvengadam I added an example for that in my answer.